# PHP: Convert array string to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

My String is

```
["Alchemy","Alchemy-w","Alchemy-b"]
```

How can I made it to like

```
Array (
        [0] => Alchemy
        [1] => Alchemy-w
        [2] => Alchemy-b
}
```

Please help me, How I Can get this output in a Stranded manner else I have to cut it using sub-string or any other ordinary php functions.

Comment: Is your string a JSON?

Comment: maybe `json_decode()` or `unserialize()` or `$array = explode(',', $string)`

Comment: I think it is not JSON

Comment: how do you get above mentioned format result ?

Comment: @AmbalMani I got this result from an API

Comment: @vikujangid May be you mentioned format is json passiblity 95%, bcoz most of API response as json format.

Answer (score 4):

the string is a valid json-string. so you could use json_decode:

```
$json = '["Alchemy","Alchemy-w","Alchemy-b"]';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string is json. just do this:

```
<?php
$json = '["Alchemy","Alchemy-w","Alchemy-b"]';
$array = json_decode($json, true); //When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. 

echo "<pre>"; //to get it displayed nicely
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is json format only, you can use following mathod.

```
$resp = '["Alchemy","Alchemy-w","Alchemy-b"]';
print_r(json_decode($resp));
```